# Interface Builder Bug?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, nsmenuitem, nsmatrix

I have a cocoa program that I have I am writing on a 10.6 system, but targeting to 10.5.

On the 10.6 system, it works fine. However, when I run it on the 10.5 machine, I get:

> The sender of menu item actions is
>   now the NSMenuItem, not an NSMatrix. A
>   menu item action method appears to be
>   trying to send the NSMatrix method
>   'accessibilityIsIgnored' to its
>   sender. This is no longer valid.
>   Please change the code.

I looked this up online and found  that one place implies that I'm calling "accessibilityIsIgnored" in my code, which I am not, or that there are multiple copies of the InterfaceBuilder library on the system, which there are not.

has anyone else seen this?

Comment: Try setting a breakpoint on `-[NSMenuItem accessibilityIsIgnored]` and running your app in the Debugger.

Answer (score 0):

Open your nib files in IB and look for the little yellow warning sign in the bottom right of the nib document window. Generally IB will tell you if you have done something that only works on 10.6, but it is really quiet about it.

Comment: that's bottom left **not** bottom right. green dot means your xcode project is open.